# SilverStripe Children Of, loop only 3 times

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to make the loop run only 3 times, no matter how many it has.

```
<% loop $ChildrenOf(Sponsors) %>
        <li>
            <a href="$TargetURL" target="_blank">
                <img src="$Logo.Link" alt="image" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <% end_loop %>
```

What I thought about doing is declaring a counter variable and if it hits 3 call break, however when I do this:

```
<% $counter = 0 %>
```

the page breaks, it doesn't throw any errors but any line of code after that doesn't get rendered.

How would I make that loop break after it runs 3 times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in the [SilverStripe Templates](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates) documentation. This should work:

```
<% loop $ChildrenOf(Sponsors).Limit(3) %>
    <li>
        <a href="$TargetURL" target="_blank">
            <img src="$Logo.Link" alt="image" />
        </a>
    </li>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Thank you!,  is there a way for me to check if the loop is on its first or second iteration?

Comment: Yes, you can use one of the position indicators (e.g. $Pos) documented in the link in my answer.